# How do I get all pairs of values in a variable based on shared values in a different variable

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

My problem is perhaps a little difficult to formulate, hence I haven't found any solutions yet, but I'll try:

I wan't to find all pairs of values in a variable based on whether they share any value in another variable. Maybe the following example can illustrate it more clearly.

In a 2 variable data frame like this:

```
data.frame(scaffold = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D"), 
           geneID = c("162", "276", "64", "276", "281", "64", "162", "162"))
#>  scaffold geneID
#>         A    162
#>         A    276
#>         B     64
#>         B    276
#>         B    281
#>         C     64
#>         C    162
#>         D    162
```

... I want to find all pairs of "scaffolds" `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`, that share any of the "geneID"s `64`, `162`, `176`, and `281`, so that the above would become a data frame with all pairs of scaffolds in 2 new columns like this:

```
data.frame(V1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C"), V2 =c("B", "C", "D", "C", "D"))                                                         

#>  V1 V2
#>   A  B
#>   A  C
#>   A  D
#>   B  C
#>   C  D
```

Obviously A and B is the same pair as B and A, so these should be removed somehow, but that's probably easy. Afterwards, this data frame needs to be combined with a data frame containing x/y coordinates of the scaffolds for drawing a line between the pairs on top of a plot with the scaffolds.

I do have a working for-loop to do the job, but I need to replace that with a much faster alternative. I'll spare you the code, it's complicated and doesn't always do it right. Running it on just 20 scaffolds can take seconds, but I need to do it on thousands. I was hoping a series of `dplyr` or `data.table` functions could do the job as they probably are as fast as it gets, but I haven't been able to get my head around how.

I hope you can help me, or perhaps something similar is already in another threat I just wasn't able to find.

---

A performance comparison of the two solutions by @Florian and @Roman can be found at http://rpubs.com/kasperskytte/SO_question_48407650

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. Note that I modified your example `df` so `A` and `C` share both `162` and `64`, and we have to make sure that this group does not occur twice in the output.

```
df  = data.frame(scaffold = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D","A"), 
           geneID = c("162", "276", "64", "276", "281", "64", "162", "162","64"),stringsAsFactors = F)

y = split(df$scaffold,df$geneID)
unique(do.call(rbind,(lapply(y[which(sapply(y, length) > 1)],function(x){t(combn(sort(x),2))}))))
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "C" 
[2,] "A"  "D" 
[3,] "C"  "D" 
[4,] "A"  "B" 
[5,] "B"  "C"
```

How it works: First we split the data into groups based on `df$geneID`, the result we call `y`. Then we `lapply` over every element of `y` that has more than 1 element in it a function that gives us all `n` possible combinations of 2 as a `nx2` matrix. By calling `sort()` on `x` inside this function we make removing duplicates easier later on, because we then `rbind` this list into a large matrix, and call `unique()` on the result to remove duplicates.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Good solution. I'll mark this one as answer, because it is 5x faster than Roman's on 7000 scaffolds. 5 sec vs 1 sec, so not a big deal, but will be on even larger data :)

Comment: Written with pipes: `split <- split(df$scaffold, df$geneID);
    shared_genes <- split[which(sapply(split, length) > 1)] %>% 
      lapply(function(split) {
        sort(split) %>%
          combn(m = 2) %>%
          t()
      }) %>%
      do.call(what = rbind) %>%
      unique()`

Comment: Hi kasper, glad I could help! And your implementation with pipes looks really good, never really thought about writing it like that.

Comment: @KasperSkytteAndersen I'd be interested in seeing the timings and profilings of the code. You can edit your question to append this information if you're up for it.

Comment: Sure. Here you go. The data is on figshare: http://rpubs.com/kasperskytte/SO_question_48407650

Answer (score 0):

See the commends in the code.

```
xy <- data.frame(scaffold = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D"), 
           geneID = c("162", "276", "64", "276", "281", "64", "162", "162"))

# split by gene
xy1 <- split(xy, f = xy$geneID)

# find all combinations
out <- sapply(xy1, FUN = function(x) {
  x$scaffold <- as.character(x$scaffold)
  # add NA so that we can remove any cases that have a single scaffold
  tryCatch(t(combn(x$scaffold, 2)), error = function(e) NA)
}, simplify = FALSE)

# remove NAs and some fiddling to get the desired format
out <- out[!is.na(out)]
out <- do.call(rbind, out)

# sort the data
out <- t(apply(out, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) sort(x)))

# remove duplicates
out <- out[!duplicated(out), ]
out

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "C" 
[2,] "A"  "D" 
[3,] "C"  "D" 
[4,] "A"  "B" 
[5,] "B"  "C"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, quick solution and it worked perfectly!